# C# + XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a method that is calling a web service. When this web service is called, the following method is called:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(
    "http://mydomain.com/services/DoSomething", 
    RequestNamespace = "http://mydomain.com/services", 
    ResponseNamespace = "http://mydomain.com/services", 
    Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, 
    ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MyResponse")]

public MyResponse DoSomethingr(MyRequest myRequest)
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("DoSomething", new object[] { myRequest});
    return ((MyResponse)(results[0]));
}
```

When this method is called, I've noticed that the XML includes the following:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <!-- XML --!>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How do I remove the `<soap:>` wrappers from my XML?

Comment: Why do you want to remove those XML namespaces prefixes?? Those are part of the SOAP standard used to call web services - don't tamper with them, otherwise your SOAP call might not work anymore....

Comment: If you don't want the <soap:> wrappers then avoid using a SoapDocumentMethodAttribute.

Comment: if you remove the `<soap : >` stuff, then you're not using SOAP.  Better to use WCF, a different .NET programming model, if you don't want soap web services.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't. Soap is a standard protocol for publishing services and accessing remote data. Without it the remote server won't understand your request.